# Extract data from string, leaving out a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm totally new to regular expressions and I'm trying to get something like this:

```
["Group", "s1", "s2", "Group2"]
```

from a string:

```
string = "_GRP_Group||s1||s2||Group2||"
```

All I have now is:

```
word = re.findall(r'([^\|]+)', string)
```

which just leaves out the pipe and I get this:

```
['_GRP_Group', 's1', 's2', 'Group2']
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `_GRP_` prefix?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it, but most of them want work in the general case of the problem you are solving. In other words, you want to remove the prefix based on what? Underscores? Uppercase? Length?

Comment: hey. thanks for replying. i'd like to filter it out based on it's value: `_GRP_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments on other answers, it sounds like the `_GRP_` prefix is a prefix to the *string* rather than to each individual split value?

Try this:

```
string = "_GRP_Group||s1||s2||Group2||"
word = re.findall(r"(?:_GRP_)?([^|]+)", string)
```

Comment: Unfortunately `findall` still applies the `_GRP_` regex match to every matched group (just like the other answer does), but since it's optional and [non-capturing](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups), it won't appear in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expressions to split the first string by `||` or remove the prefix `_GRP_`.  You can just use `split` and slicing:

```
words = "_GRP_Group||s1||s2||Group2||"[5:].split('||')
```

The slice `[5:]` will exclude the first five characters from the string.
If you didn't know where `_GRP_` would occur, you could use `replace`:

```
words = "_GRP_Group||s1||s2||Group2||".split('||')
words = [word.replace("_GRP_", "") for word in words]
```

Comment: i could do that, but i thought there would be a more elegant solution using regex

Comment: Is it possible to see `string = "_GRP_Group||_GRP_s1||_GRP_s2||_GRP_Group2||"` or it is a prefix for the entire string itself?

Comment: it's a prefix for the entire string

Comment: @beatlemaniac I've updated the solution to reflect the fact that `_GRP_` will always start the string.  It seems to me to be a more elegant solution than a regex, but I suppose that's a matter of taste.